# Options to lock Header and Footer sections in Word when Visualforce Page is rendered as word

Tags: visualforce, custom, renderas, ms-word

I am looking for options to lock the header and footer sections in the word document when Visualforce page is being rendered as word. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" contentType="application/msword" cache="true">
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='https://www.w3.org/TR/html40/'>
    <head>
        <style>
            p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader{
                margin:0in;
                margin-top:.0001pt;
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
            }
            p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter{
                margin:0in;
                margin-bottom:.0001pt;
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
                
            }
            @page Section1{
                size:8.5in 11.0in; 
                margin:0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;
                mso-header-margin:0.5in;
                mso-header:h1;
                mso-footer:f1; 
                mso-footer-margin:0.5in;
                mso-paper-source:0;
            }
            div.Section1{
                page:Section1;
            }
            
            table#hrdftrtbl{
              margin:0in 0in 0in 9in;
            } 
            
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Content -->
        <!--Section1 div starts-->
        <div class="Section1">
            
            This goes in body of Word Doc?<br/>
            
            <!--Header and Footer Starts-->
            <table id='hrdftrtbl' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--Header-->
                        <div style='mso-element:header' id="h1" >
                                <p class="MsoHeader">
                                    <table border="1" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="100%">
                                                <p>This is Header section.</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    <td>
                    <!--Footer-->
                    <div style='mso-element:footer' id="f1">
                            <p class="MsoFooter">
                                <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%">
                                            <p>This is Footer section.</p>
                                             
                                        </td> 
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div><!--Section1 div ends-->
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```